# Why does jQuery use 'deep' while checking conflicts with the global object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was observing the source code of the jQuery library, and I noticed one thing. At the end of the whole library, a method checks if there is any other function called *jQuery* or *$* on the global object.

Anyway, here is that method:

```
var

    // Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
    _jQuery = window.jQuery,

    // Map over the $ in case of overwrite
    _$ = window.$;

jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
    if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
        window.$ = _$;
    }

    if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
};
```

I couldn't understand what `deep` actually does here. How having a deep copy situation can change the result of that function?

Comment: From the doc :A Boolean indicating whether to remove all jQuery variables from the global scope (including jQuery itself).: ref: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to jQuery's [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), the function `jQuery.noConflict()` restores the global variable `window.$` to its previous value, from before jQuery was initialized:

> Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using `$`. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of `$` are saved during jQuery initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them.

When initialized, jQuery overwrites the global variable `$`. If you are using another library that writes to `window.$`, jQuery might overwrite `window.$`, causing the other library to break.

In such cases, you can call `jQuery.noConflict()` to have jQuery restore `window.$` to its previous value. Since jQuery is also available through `window.jQuery`, you can still use jQuery after calling `noConfilct()` (for example by writing `window.jQuery("#id")`).

But what if you are running two versions of jQuery on the same page? In this case, the second version will overwrite both `window.$` and `window.jQuery`, which means you won't have access to the first version of jQuery after the second version initializes.

This is where the `deep` parameter comes into play. This parameter isn't related to "deep copy", it's more like a "deep clean". calling `jQuery.noConflict(true)` restores *both* `window.$` and `window.jQuery`. If you call this function from the second version you loaded, it will restore the first version into the global scope.

Now let's take another look at the code you mentioned:

```js
var
    _jQuery = window.jQuery, // Store the previous value of `window.jQuery`
    _$ = window.$; // Store the previous value of `window.$`

jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
    if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
        window.$ = _$; // Restore `window.$` to the value we previously stored in the variable
    }

    if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery; // If called with the parameter `deep`, also restore `window.jQuery`
    }

    return jQuery; // Return a reference to this version of jQuery
};
```